# the table "stock" doesn't exist jpa and spring-boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Everything was working well until I use the annotation @ManyToOne in the class 'Stock', it generates the error:

"Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'libraries.stock' doesn't exist"

the implementation of the class "Stock":

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
@Entity
@Table(name="stock")
@Data
public class Stock {
@EmbeddedId
private stockid id;

private int quantity;
public Stock(int qq) {
    this.quantity = qq;
}
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
private Book book ;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "library_id")
private Library library ;   
}
```

Comment: How does the `Library` class look in relation to `Stock`.

Comment: @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "library")     
 private List<Stock> stock_library;

Comment: Do you have mapping table between Library and Stock in DB?